# scan a cell, with 2 variables ( cells(i,j) )

Tags: excel, vba

My string 'strings' does not get any data from the lines where it was supposed to get the data from the cell ( corY, i ).

Here is my code:

```
Dim strings As String

corY = 2

For i = 5 To 20

strings = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(corY, i)).Value

MsgBox (strings)


Next i
```

Comment: Maybe more complicated than this, but did you mean `strings = Active....etc` rather than `stings`

Comment: Besides the `stings`-Typo: Your variable `k` is set?

Comment: Yes, I just posted a small amount of the code let me correct that in the edit

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(corY, i).Value` (get rid of `Range`). I am surprised that you don't get a Runtime error?!

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(corY, i))` can be simplified to `Cells(corY, i)`. Better would be to replace it with an actual reference to the worksheet you're using instead of assuming that the active one is the correct sheet.

Comment: Hey FunThomas, I just change what you told me, but the msgbox is still emlpty, it should return a string. weird... 
My variables croY and i are set as double, would that be an issue?

Comment: use `Long` for row numbers, and please include all relevant code.

Comment: Just to confirm, you're getting values from row 2, columns E to T?  Your current code starts with cell `E2`, then `F2`, then `G2` and so on, are those the correct cells?

Comment: `Long` would be better that `double`, but that's not your issue. Are you sure that you  are accessing the right cell of the right worksheet? Not that `Cells` have the parameters in the order row / column

Comment: argh,, the code was changed during my tests... @Tom is right.

Comment: And you don't have the infamous `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: I dont have the infamous error in my code. 
I don't know what would be the issue, as I am testing that code with a excelspreadsheet full of data, so I can see what data is read ... 

I will review my code with your advices and come back when I have relevant informations

Comment: Thanks everyone, 

As stated it was a silly mistake, tigeravatar pointed that I might read the wrong cells And Fun Thomas explained that cells have the parameters row/column. 

I mixed the order and got really confused.

Thanks everyone else for the advices, I really love this community .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of "range" and then "cells". This works for me with a strings in the "B" column of excel.

```
 Sub test5()

 Dim strings As String
 Dim k As Integer

 k = 5
 i = 2

 corY = 2

 For i = 2 To k

 strings = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, corY).Value

 MsgBox (strings)


 Next i

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
strings = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(corY, i)).Value
```

with:

```
strings = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(corY, i).Value
```

**NOTES:**

A single `Cells()` inside `Range()` does not work.  However, here are some examples of setting a range that will work:

```
Sub examples()
    Dim r As Range

    Set r = Workbooks("qwerty.xlsm").Worksheets("Junp").Range("A1:B15")
    Set r = Worksheets("Junp").Range("A1:B15")
    Set r = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(15, 2))
    Set r = Range("Junp!A1:B15")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By using something like the following you get a feedback which range is actually displayed:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ShowCells()
    Dim myString As String
    Dim myRange As Range
    'Dim iCt As Integer, corY As Integer
    Dim iCt As Long, corY As Long
    corY = 2
    For iCt = 5 To 20
        Set myRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(corY, iCt)
        myString = myRange.Value
        MsgBox (myRange.Address & ":" & myString)
    Next iCt
End Sub
```

Comment: (I suggest using `Long` over `Integer` for rows, as Excel's total rows exceeds what `Integer` can hold).